# Is my proof right? (Convergence of a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(p_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $X$ and suppose that some subsequence $(p_{n_i})$ converges to $p\in X$. Prove that $(p_n)$ converges to $p$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $\varepsilon >0$, since $(p_{n_i})$ converges to $p$, there exists $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that: $d(p_{n_i},p)<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, $\forall n_i\geq N_1$.

Also, since $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there exists $N_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that: $d(p_n,p_m)<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, $\forall n\geq N_2$.

Let $N=\max (N_1,N_2)$, since $(p_{n_i})$ is a subsequence of $(p_n)$ then for each $n\geq N$ we would have:$$d(p_n,p)\leq d(p_n,p_{n_i})+d(p_{n_i},p)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon .$$Which completes the proof.

I just want to make sure everything looks ok. Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you write because you mix the variables $n$, $n_i$ and $i$. For the definition of $N_1$ you should work with $i$. For the final argument you may explain how you find a good $n_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite well, but there's a small problem in the first line of the proof.
We consider the sequence $(p_{n_i})_{i\in\Bbb N}$, which is indexed by $i$, not $n_i$. Since it's convergent, there exists $N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(p_{n_i},p)< \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $i\geq N_1$.

Moreover, the Cauchy definition needs correction: there exists $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that  $d(p_n,p_m)<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $m,n\geq N_2$.

Now, if $i\geq N=\max (N_1,N_2)$ then $i\geq N_2$ and $n_i\geq i\geq N_2$ and therefore $d(p_i,p_{n_i})<\frac{\varepsilon}2$.

Now the last estimate is correct:
$$d(p_i,p)\leq d(p_i,p_{n_i})+d(p_{n_i},p)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon .$$